# Limiting rows in SQL doesn't work properly

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I want to get the first 5 rows of every season in my select. I have 4 seasons: `SUM, SPR, AUT, WIN`.
So there should be 20 rows in total.
My select looks like this:

```
select *
from (
    select year, season, ROUND(avg(temperature),1) as avgTemp
    from temperature join month on temperature.MONTH = month.MONTH
    group by (season, year)
    order by season, avgTemp asc
) where rownum <= 5;
```

It works for just one season. The output is:

```
1993    AUT 8,7
2007    AUT 9,9
1996    AUT 10
1998    AUT 10
2008    AUT 10,5
```

But it should look like that:

```
 1996 SPR        9.6
  1991 SPR       10.3
  2006 SPR       10.3
  2004 SPR       10.6
  1995 SPR       10.6
  1996 SUM       18.9
  1993 SUM       19.1
  2007 SUM       19.5
  1998 SUM       19.5
  2000 SUM       19.6
  1993 AUT        8.7
  2007 AUT        9.9
  1998 AUT       10.0
  1996 AUT       10.0
  2008 AUT       10.5
  1996 WIN         .3
  1991 WIN        1.2
  2003 WIN        1.6
  2006 WIN        1.9
  2005 WIN        2.0
```

Do you know how to improve the select or do you have any other suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: duplicate accounts?

Comment: Was logged in with a other account. This one is mine

Comment: This query is called *Top N Per Group* and there are tons of examples on how to write this for SQL Server, those which use CTEs and row number and others which don't depending on your version of SQL Server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do it in three steps:

1. Group by season and year, calculating the average temperature
2. Assign a row number: it restart with each season and assigns in ascending order according to the average temperature
3. Select only the rows with a row number between 1 and 5

The SQL should look like this (untested):

```
select year, season, avg_temp
from (
    select year, season, avg_temp,
        row_number() over(partition by season order by avg_temp) rn
    from (
        select year, season, ROUND(avg(temperature),1) as avg_temp
        from temperature
        join month on temperature.MONTH = month.MONTH
        group by season, year
    )
)
where rn <= 5;
```

**Update**

For you special ordering by season, add this:

```
order by case season
        when 'SPR' then 1
        when 'SUM' then 2
        when 'AUT' then 3
        when 'WIN' then 4
    end, avg_temp;
```

Comment: Thank you Codo, this one works! The last thing I want to know is how can I order by the season starting with `SPR` as above shown?

Comment: I've added how you can do the sorting, which I forgot in my original answer. As sorting alphabetically would result in the wrong order, you need to assign numbers to the seasons.

Comment: Works like a charm!

Comment: Apart from that, do you have any suggestions how to sort the values top-down per season. So that the highest avgTemp of these 5 rows is the first one and not the last one?

Comment: So you want the highest average temperatures for each season and you want them displayed top down in the output? If so, you need to add `DESC` after both `ORDER BY` clauses: `order by avg_temp` in `over` clause and `... end, avg_temp desc` at the very end.

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Comment: Sorry but do you know why I get here a `NOT A GROUP BY EXPRESSION` error? select name, cartype, sales
from (
    select name, cartype, sales,
        row_number() over(partition by name order by sales) rn
    from (
        select name, cartype, sales
        from sales
        join regions on sales.REGIONID = regions.REGIONID join cars on sales.CARID = cars.CARID
        group by name
    )
)
where rn <= 3;

Comment: It's the inner-most SELECT. The SELECT may only contain expressions you group by or expressions using an aggregate functions. Otherwise grouping makes no sense. However, you have `name, cartype, sales` as SELECT and `name` as GROUP BY. This doesn't match.

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH cteAverageTempByYearBySeason AS (
    SELECT
       year
       ,season
       ,ROUND(AVG(temperature),1) as AvgTemp
    FROM
       Temperature t
       INNER JOIN Month m
       On t.MONTH = m.MONTH
    GROUP BY
       year
       ,season
)

, cteRowNumber AS (
    SELECT
       *
       ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY season ORDER BY AvgTemp ASC) as RowNumber
    FROM
       cteAverageTempByYearBySeason
)

SELECT *
FROM
    cteRowNumber
WHERE
    RowNumber <= 5
```

Here is an example.  I broke out the *derived tables* into *Common Table Expressions* to make the logic more noticeable.  You need to create a `PARTITIONED ROW_NUMBER()` not just use oracles special `rownumber`.  The latter will only return the same as `TOP/LIMIT 5` where as the former will allow you to identify 5 rows per season.

Edit added a neat trick for your order by so you don't have to write a case expression.  This one utilizes your month number which I assume is what `MONTH` column is.

```
WITH cteAverageTempByYearBySeason AS (
    SELECT
       year
       ,season
       ,ROUND(AVG(temperature),1) as AvgTemp
       ,MAX(m.MONTH) as SeasonOrderBy
    FROM
       Temperature t
       INNER JOIN Month m
       On t.MONTH = m.MONTH
    GROUP BY
       year
       ,season
)

, cteRowNumber AS (
    SELECT
       *
       ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY season ORDER BY AvgTemp ASC) as RowNumber
    FROM
       cteAverageTempByYearBySeason
)

SELECT
    year
    ,season
    ,AVG
FROM
    cteRowNumber
WHERE
    RowNumber <= 5
ORDER BY
    SeasonOrderBy
    ,AvgTemp
    ,Year
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `row_number` to get 5 rows for each grouping:

```
select
    year,
    season,
    round(avg(temperature), 1) as avgTemp
from (
    select *,
        row_number() over(partition by season, year order by season, avgTemp) as rn
    from temperature t
    join month m
        on m.MONTH = t.MONTH
) a
where
    a.rn <= 1
```

Comment: I get the following error: `"FROM keyword not found where expected"`